# How can i save the jquery click changes after click? (Serverside)

Tags: jquery, cookies, click, mousedown, .post

i am trying to make a (who is here) overview page for the employees at my work.

I have this .click function running now, and i gave every person an ID.

fx. if i go and click to change my status then how is it possible for someone to open a browser on another computer and see that i changed the option from 'working' to 'not working'?

I read that it is maby possible to do with jQuery Cookie or AJAX.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.working').hide();
$('#martin .off-work').show(); //. why do i have only martin tag here?
$('.oversigt').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var t = $(this);
  t.hide().siblings('.oversigt').show();
});
```

```css
  * {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .oversigt {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
  .off-work {
    background: red;
  }
  .working {
    background: lime
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Gardeners</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:50%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:50%">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Hanne</td>
      <td id="hanne">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Lars</td>
      <td id="lars">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Bent</td>
      <td id="bent">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Steen-Allan</td>
      <td id="sa">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td id="jacob">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Steen Urth</td>
      <td id="su">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Elsebeth</td>
      <td id="elsebeth">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Pia</td>
      <td id="pia">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Dorthe</td>
      <td id="dorthe">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Martin</td>
      <td id="martin">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Jesper</td>
      <td id="jesper">
        <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
        <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
i saw the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EHbBHm5l4g about post and get (he just tells how i can send the value of a input.) and i made a file called jfunc.js with this code, i made a store.php file with no code (yet).

I dont understand how i can make .working show instead of hide.

```
$('#name') .on('click', function() {
```

var name = $ ('#martin') .val();
  $.post('store.php', {name: name }, function(data) {

});
} );

Comment: do you mean to save it on server side?

Comment: Yes, i dont think i would need to use a database like mySQL. i will just edit the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you will need to let other users from other computers to see what you clicked on, this will need a server side storage to save the selected values and read them.
You can use [jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send selected values to server side code (server side code is based on your language - could be php, c#,...)
And save selected values in any storage (database, Application Session variables, xml file,...) then read from the server side using [jquery get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) of you need to read in ajax style, or just load selected values on page load.